# Is there a function to subset data using a qualitative requirement in a column?

Tags: r, subset

I am having trouble creating a subset for a large dataframe. I need to extract all rows that match one of two correct cities in one of the columns, however any subset that I create ends up empty. Given the main dataframe, I try:

```
New = data[data$Home.port %in% c("ARDGLASS","NEWLYN")]
```

However R returns "undefined columns selected"

Answer (score 3):

A comma is missing:

```
New = data[data$Home.port %in% c("ARDGLASS","NEWLYN"), ]
```

That is because you are selecting rows, not columns; if you leave out the comma, `R` tries to subset columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use data.table so:

```
# install.packages(data.table)
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
new_data <- data[Home.port %in% c("ARDGLASS","NEWLYN")]
```

You can check [this web](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) to learn data.table is very fast with big data bases

Answer (score 0):

The subset function will also do this task

```
new <- subset(data, subset = Home.port %in% c("ARDGLASS","NEWLYN"))
```

The base approach is functionally the same, its just a matter of using a declarative function for the task or not.

Answer (score 0):

When using subset() the first argument is the data frame you want to subset. When you want to check for several variables you do not need to put "data$" in front. This save time and makes it easier to read.

`datasubset <- subset(data, Home.port %in% c("ARDGLASS","NEWLYN"))`

You can also use multiple conditions to subset use "&" for AND condition or "|" for OR condition depending on what you plan to do.

`datasubset <- subset(data, Home.port == "ARDGLASS" & Home.port == "NEWLYN"))`